# Implementing OnSubmit with httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, onsubmit

I am new to C# and just messing around with it myself, now, i have been trying to create a WinForm that can post some parameters in a webpage and do something something on the resultant webpage obtained. Now I have accomplished this on a page that uses POST method, But i am not able to do so with A webpage that has a html code like this :

```
<form method="post" action="test.asp" name=FrontPage_Form1 onsubmit="return FrontPage_Form1_Validator(this)">
      <div align="center"><center><p>
      <input name="name" size="8" maxlength=8><font color="#faebd7">---
```

Now i don't how How To implement this "ONSUBMIT" with HttpWebRequest..

This is my current Code :

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://cbseresults.nic.in/aieee/cbseaieee.asp");
            request.Method = "POST";
            string r = "regno=" + rno.ToString();
            Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r);

      request.ContentLength = Bytes.Length;
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        RequestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        RequestStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
        RequestStream.Close();

        Response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader ResponseStream = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
        string Result = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
        ResponseStream.Close();
```

But its not working, Any Help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) in order to understand what the page is sending and receiving from the server.
Then make the request as it is shown in fiddler...

You can also use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to open some pages or sending and receiving data from server.

There are some ways to click on buttons or links:

1. Use a `WebBrowser` object in your app and Iterate through objects on the page by using `SelectNextControl` method of `WebBrowser` object and then sending `Enter` key like so: `SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");`
2. Using `JavaScript` and invoking functions and reading elements using `getElementById` and some other methods